# how to make Font Awesome icon stretched horizontally with the message box and added picture to be into an uniform circle as design (bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am meeting 2 problems and here they are. First, i followed my tutorial and the pictures are not as uniform as design.

As you can see in these pictures. The first is my tutorial and the second is my coded.

[image: my design 1]

[image: my problem 1]

My second problem is, when I coded, the font awesome icon does not stretch as expected. As you can see in the third picture is the tutorial the the fourth is what I got

[image: my design 2]

[image: my problem 2]

So, my question is, first, how can I make the photos to be into an uniform circle as design ? And my second question is, how can I make Font Awesome icon stretched horizontally with the message box ?

I am coding these by bootstrap 5

Here is my code

```
https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/project2.3
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout code blow. it's maybe help you.

```css
.img-box {
            width:  100px;
            height:  100px;
            display:  inline-block;
            vertical-align:  top;
        marg
        }
        .img-box img {
            width:  100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
            border-radius:  50%;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row g-3">
            <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                        <div class="img-box mb-3">
                            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1664575198263-269a022d6e14?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" title="" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h6>Card Heading</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                        <div class="img-box mb-3">
                            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1670747375356-6efaa71ec623?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" title="" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h6>Card Heading</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                        <div class="img-box mb-3">
                            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1670787053502-ad4b741ef37a?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw4fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" title="" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h6>Card Heading</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6 col-lg-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                        <div class="img-box mb-3">
                            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1670777361177-7ea502ee059d?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwxMnx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" title="" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <h6>Card Heading</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Thanks all of you for your answer, the code ran very well. But how about my font awesome problem ? Anyway to solve that problem ?